# Unable to insert null values using setNull into the MySql database using Java on the fly?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to the set null values on runtime depending on the type I get

**Here is my code**

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
// input can be Intger,Date, BigInt etc which Mysql supports
String input = "."+st.getType();
// param :- java.sql.Types.Integer or java.sql.Types.BigInt
Class clazz = Class.forName("java.sql.Types");
Field field = clazz.getField(input);
int val = field.getInt(null);
pstmt.setNull(1,val);
```

Comment: use `Integer` instead of int. int can only be 0 while Integer can also be null

Comment: Ok not the problem of that. suppose I want to insert for BigInt on coderun i.e not manually setting to java.sql.Types.BigInt. How to do that?

Comment: what is `st`?  Where is it declared and how is it initialized?

Comment: @IanMcLaird I have a class Stateros . It's object is st and st.getType() would give me it's either varchar or Date or Integer..

Comment: Are you getting an exception?  `NoSuchFieldException` for example?

Comment: Also, what is the return type of `st.getType()`?  `int`?  `String`?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is `st`, why the reflection magic?

Comment: I'm still unclear why, knowing the statement you created, you wouldn't know the type of a particular parameter.  You're trying to reflect something that shouldn't be changing.  Parameter `1` of `pstmt` should always have the same type, shouldn't it?  Why would it be different?

Comment: Ok I will make it as simple as I can. Lets say there are 4 columns in MySql Database of types varchar, Date, int, bool. Now to insert a null value in the respective column I need to know the type( like java.sql.Types.*) . So in the String input I am trying to get the types (i.e varchar, Date,int or bool) and also I am getting an Object as input from an another function such as (Object obj = new Integer("4")).  The case here is (Object obj = null). In the above code (st.gettype) actually has as arraylist of these 4 sql types I mentioned. Hope so you got it? @IanMcLaird

Comment: I tried reflection, but it isn't working. I have given the example in the above comment to IanMclaird. I want you to take a look at it. @MarkRotteveel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to slightly challenge your question in this answer.  I do not believe that you need to do what you are doing, but as it's somewhat unclear, I'll do what I can to help you out.

First, based on the variable name `pstmt` I'm going to guess that this is a `PreparedStatement` that looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (my_int, my_date, my_varchar, my_bool) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);
```

If this is the case, then you don't need to do any reflection at all, because Parameter 1 will *always* be an `INTEGER`, Parameter 2 will *always* be a `DATE` and so on.  So you know what type to use in `setNull` because you know the position already (because you have to, because it's the first argument to `setNull`), and you know the statement.  It's generally going to be much easier to follow your code if you just do the obvious thing and set the values.

```
if (myInt != null) {
    pstmt.setInt(1, myInt);
} else {
    pstmt.setNull(1, Types.INTEGER);
}
pstmt.setDate(2, myDate);  // already handles null
// and so on
```

Now, this might get a tad trickier if you're trying to set the columns in a loop for some reason.  I suggest to you that this is a bad idea because it'll be less obvious to future developers what you're up to.

However, the JDBC API has `setObject` for just such an occasion.  `setObject` will allow `null` values, so you don't have to handle the `null` and `not-null` cases separately.  There's even a version of `setObject` that will allow you to do this *without* specifying the type.  In that case, it's just:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myObjects.size(); ++i) {
    Object obj = myObjects.get(i);
    pstmt.setObject(i, obj);
}
```

No casting, no remembering the type, no reflection needed.  The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject(int,%20java.lang.Object)) says it's not supported by every database, but I'd give this a shot before you do reflection.

## Now to Answer Your Question

If, for some reason, you *need* to do this with reflection (because you're one of the unlucky few whose database doesn't support un-typed nulls), you were actually pretty close.

```
public void apply(PreparedStatement pstmt, int param, String typeName, Object value) {
    try {
        Class<?> types = Types.class;
        Field field = types.getField(typeName);
        int typeValue = field.getInt(null);

        pstmt.setObject(param, obj, typeValue);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle exceptions
    }
}
```

So what's different here from what you were trying?  First, the field name doesn't have a `.` in front of it.  That's not part of the field name.  Secondly, the `typeName` parameter here must exactly match the `java.sql.Types` field name.  This is a case-sensitive `String`.  So, for example it's `"INTEGER"` not `"int"`.  In your comment, you indicated that your `st.getType()` method had an `ArrayList`.  I've assumed that this method returns a single string, based on its knowledge of the query.  Just make sure that your type names are the same as the names used by `java.sql.Types` and that the object in question can actually be *used as* (cast / converted to) that type.

Comment: Cool explanation. Thanks :)